# Configuring AWS RDS in a Spring Boot Application running on AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to learn my way of developing a REST app via Spring Boot framework using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk infrastructure. I am using the IntelliJ IDE to develop and test the app on my local box before deploying it to the AWS Elastic BeanStalk server. I am trying to talk to the AWS RDS instance in my app. With the following code snippets my app is able to talk to RDS instance when deployed and run against my local box but gives me http 404 when deployed on the AWS server which i guess is because the deploy failed due to failure to connect to the RDS instance from AWS.

[Project POM file](https://github.com/AsaNeAsa/PlayBigBackendApp/blob/master/pom.xml)

[Application Properties file](https://github.com/AsaNeAsa/PlayBigBackendApp/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties)

[User Repository file](https://github.com/AsaNeAsa/PlayBigBackendApp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/asaneasa/sports/playbigbackend/repositories/UserRepository.java)

I am looking for a correct way to configure these secrets so that they are not present in the git. Ideally take it from AWS environment variables defined for the instance but i am not able to figure out how the spring boot application properties files can access AWS Elastic BeanStalk environment configuration variables.

I have read some documents and tutorials but not exactly able to figure this out. Like [Spring Cloud SDK](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_amazon_sdk_configuration), [Sample Spring Boot AWS App](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/aws-refapp)

**[Edit 1]** To provide more information, I was able to ssh into the box and observe the logs. The point of interest is :

Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::486695215273:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-dc86381f is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResources (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 1ee8c03b-ecd4-11e5-9fe1-378ce4cb26d3)

**[Edit 2]** After adding AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess security policy in the required policy, 
Stack for i-dc86381f does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: f579cc15-ecd4-11e5-a20b-114992e25084)

My template file as mentioned in AWSCloudFormation is [My Template File](https://gist.github.com/aditya2kx/a5f6894116ea7ab97f0b)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Elastic Beanstalk "secrets", or environment variables, can be done via the cli or via the GUI.  For the cli use:

`eb setenv ExampleVar=ExampleValue`

Which is pretty straight forward.  Docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html

To do it via the GUI you'll navigate to your application and the desired environment, click on Configuration in the left hand menu. Click the gear icon on the "Software Configuration" panel, and you'll be taken to the the configuration page where you can set "Environment Properties", which are key/value pairs... You can set a property name and then the property value and when you click "apply" they'll be applied to your environment and then your application can access them however it would normally access environment variables in production.